# How to start with "x" seconds in the Timer

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to open my form and that the timer starts with 10 seconds, then 11, then 12, etc.

Code:

```
public static Stopwatch swTimer;

swTimer = new Stopwatch();

<ImaginaryCode>
SwTimer = 10;
</ImaginaryCode>

swTimer.Start();
```

Easy way to perfom this??

Comment: Why not just add 10 seconds when displaying the timer?

Comment: What you mean by 10,11,12 sec...? You want to start a timer beginning from 10 sec while open the form?

Comment: `typeof(Stopwatch).GetField("_elapsed", BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(swTimer, 10 * 10000 * 1000)` For the relevant math, see [https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Stopwatch.cs,12](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Stopwatch.cs,12)

Comment: @gurkan Yes, start the timer beginning from 10 sec, just adding 1 second every second.

Comment: @gurkan Im using asp.net, in my form.cs.

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă IS this a good link to study about this subject? Or if you have a better one, I appreciate you share

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă If I saw that code in a code review I would question the programmer's ability to continue on my project. Using reflection to set a private property just to display something different? No.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I just pointed about how OP can achieve what he wanted to do, I didn't say it was good practice.

Answer (score 1):

**Timer.aspx**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label> seconds passed.
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick"></asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

**Timer.aspx.cs**

```
private static int _beginSec = 10;

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Label1.Text = _beginSec++.ToString();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot force the stopwatch to start at a specified time.
You can however simply add 10,000 milliseconds when you measure the elapsed time.

```
Stopwatch swTimer = new Stopwatch();
swTimer.Start();
//Do stuff
swTimer.Stop();

//Elapsed seconds, rounding down to the nearest second.
int seconds = (swTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds + 10000) / 1000;
```

Or you can just add 10 seconds if you're using seconds.

```
Stopwatch swTimer = new Stopwatch();
swTimer.Start();
//Do stuff
swTimer.Stop();

//Elapsed seconds, rounding down to the nearest second.
int seconds = (swTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000) + 10;
```

Edit: If you're trying to limit the time to a specific timespan, then you might possibly want to use a Timer instead(like a stopwatch, but goes down.)